# Как можно получить содержимое div в asp.net web forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Здравствуйте,подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сразу в переменную считать содержимое div?
например в jquery есть метод .html() есть ли что то похоже в asp.net. Спасибо заранее.

```
string div_1=....;
```

Comment: Очень некорректный вопрос. Возможно хочется вырендерить контрол в переменную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это разные вещи. Нужно различать клиентскую часть и серверную. ASP.Net - это на стороне сервера.

1. Пользователь запрашивает страницу. На сервер шлется запрос.
2. Тут уже работает ASP.NET - читает базу, производит какие-то интенсивные вычисления, по темплейтам создает html страницу и отправляет обратно пользователю.
3. Пользователь видит результат в браузере. Тут уже начинается клиентская часть, в браузере отображается html, css, запускается javascript (jquery и т.д.)
4. Из браузера на сервер вы можете передать информацию, либо открыв новую страницу и передав параметры в адресе страницы (GET), либо отправив html форму (POST), либо ajax-ом (jquery.post(), jquery.get())
5. Т.е. содержимое div можно отправить на сервер (ASP.Net) с помощью jquery.post, на сервере ASP.Net все это как-то обработает, отправит обратно результат, который можно отобразить или выполнить (если отправили javascript)
   Web - это браузер, сервер и связь через http протокол. Браузер и сервер ничего не знают о внутренней реализации друг друга. Поэтому на сервере может быть любая технология - ASP.Net, PHP, Ruby и т.д. На клиенте может использоваться любая javascript библиотека (jquery, angular, backbone и т.д.)

Answer (score 1):

Предлагают тут решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162093/get-the-html-rendered-by-asp-net-control-in-code-behind

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb); 
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw); 
ctrl.RenderControl(hw); 
var html = sb.ToString();
```

Только одно но: на клиенте html может меняться js-ом, и это без извращений, не узнать